# React Native: How to use it correctly?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, native

I learn react native. Help me understand the following questions:

1) Is it possible to do complex UI components? If Yes, how? For example:

- [link1](https://i0.wp.com/androidtv.news/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Live-Channels_20160102_065818.jpg?fit=1920%2C1080&ssl=)
- [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srwTl.png)

2) Is it possible to use js libraries which use DOM and WebGL? For example the babylon.js.  If Yes, how?

3) Without computer on iOS I can't make an app for iPhone? If Yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do complex ui components. There are tons of libraries and tutorials if you want more informations, just google it.

No, but there are libraries with their own implementations of webgl.

No you can't, you still need xcode to compile your code for ios.